# Setting PostgreSQL privileges for a remote connection

Tags: postgresql

I want to set a user which I can use remote, that for a database can:

- do any rows operations
- can't add new columns
- can't delete/create database or tables
- I don't want the user to have access to other databases

I executed:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "example" to user_name;
REVOKE CREATE ON DATABASE "example" FROM user_name;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO user_name;
```

The following fails:

```
REVOKE CREATE ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public FROM user_name;

    invalid privilege type CREATE for relation
```

Can you, please, add all necessary steps.

Also,:

1. some help to what to set in pg_admin drop, to import only data remotely.
2. In Ubuntu set/activate full search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to keep the user from crating tables in schema `public`.

For that, you must revoke the `CREATE` privilege on that schema which is by default granted to everybody:

```
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA public FROM PUBLIC;
```

If you want to user to have permissions on tables that will be created in the future, consider using `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`.

Comment: if I remove it from public (all), because I granted him the all privilegies, will not remain create on him ? what about blocking the drop of database and table

Comment: No, you didn't grant the user any privileges on the schema, only on the database and the tables. Only the owner and superusers can drop objects, so all you have to make sure is that `user_name` does not won anything.